# How to directly add color to Heatmap series in LightningChartJS?

Tags: javascript, matrix, charts, heatmap, lightningchart

I went through the example Heatmap using IntensityGrid. It shows how to add data to the series to create Heatmap. But I want to create Heatmap directly from color. I do see there is an option to achieve this in LightningChartJS using

```
heatmap.invalidateColorsOnly( Matrix<Color> )
```

But i am not finding any reference on how to do this. Can someone please help me with this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Heatmap Mesh example](https://www.arction.com/lightningchart-js-interactive-examples/examples/lcjs-example-0801-heatmapMesh.html) from the [enter link description here](https://www.arction.com/lightningchart-js-interactive-examples/)LightningChart JS Interactive Examples shows how to use the `invalidateColorsOnly` API. The example is using Mesh type of Intensity Series but the API use is same for Grid.

The `invalidateColorsOnly` API requires that [`IndividualPointFill`](https://www.arction.com/lightningchart-js-api-documentation/v1.3.0/classes/individualpointfill.html) is used as the fillstyle for it do anything.

```js
heatmap.setFillStyle( new IndividualPointFill() )
heatmap.invalidateColorsOnly( ( row, column ) => ColorHSV( Math.random() * 70, 0.8 ) )
```

The `invalidateColorsOnly` can either take a callback function as the argument with which you can calculate a new color for each point based on row and column or a full matrix of colors that will be applied to each point. If using the matrix of colors then the color matrix should be same size as the resolution of the heatmap.

Below you can see the Heatmap mesh example from LightningChart JS interactive examples modified for Grid type heatmap.

```js
// Extract required parts from LightningChartJS.
const {
    lightningChart,
    IntensitySeriesTypes,
    IndividualPointFill,
    ColorHSV
} = lcjs

// Helper function to help turn degrees to radians
function degToRad( angle ) {
    return angle * Math.PI / 180
}

// Resolution of each row/column, specifying how many cells
// are in the heatmap.
const resolution = 20

// Create a new ChartXY.
const chart = lightningChart().ChartXY()
chart.setTitle('Heatmap using IntensityGrid')

// Add a heatmap to the chart, as a IntensityGrid
const heatmap = chart
    .addHeatmapSeries( {
        rows: resolution,
        columns: resolution,
        start: { x: 10, y: 10 },
        end: { x: 1990, y: 1990 },
        pixelate: true,
        type: IntensitySeriesTypes.Grid
    } )
    // Add colors and invalidate the Series based on the colors assigned.
    .invalidateColorsOnly( ( row, column ) => ColorHSV( Math.random() * 70, 0.8 ) )
    // Use IndividualPointFill to apply individual color per cell.
    .setFillStyle( new IndividualPointFill() )
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@arction/lcjs@1.3.0/dist/lcjs.iife.js"></script>
```